# How to replace a string in multiple files using grep and sed when the -i argument is not supported?

Tags: macos, unix, sed, grep

I have tried this command,

```
grep '/static' dir/* | xargs sed -i 's/\/static//g'
```

but the version of sed I am using does not support the -i argument.

To replace a string in a file, to the same input file as the output, I normally do this:

```
sed 's/\/static//g' filename.txt > new_filename.txt ; mv new_filename.txt filename.txt
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

OS X's version of `sed` does support `-i`, but it *requires* an argument to tell it what file extension to use for the backup file (or `""` for no backup). BTW, you want `grep -l` to get just the filenames.

```
grep -l '/static' dir/* | xargs sed -i "" 's/\/static//g'
```

Comment: It worked! I was not giving an extension for the backup file. Trowing that in there made it work. This is definitely easier to remember than going through a for loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use perl:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 's@/static@@g' dir/*
```

Comment: I was hoping for an answer using grep and sed since I don't know a lick of perl. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: In this limited scenario, Perl is quite similar to `sed`.  You can convert simple `sed` scripts to Perl with the `s2p` tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a loop:

```
for file in $(grep -l '/static' dir/*) ; do
    sed 's/\/static//g' $file > $file.$$ && mv $file.$$ $file
done
```

I use the `.$$` suffix (`$$` is the process id of the current shell) to avoid collisions with existing file names, and `&&` rather than `;` to avoid clobbering the input file if the `sed` command fails for some reason. I also added `-l` so grep prints file names rather than matching lines.

Or you can install GNU sed (I'm not sure exactly how to do that on OSX).

Comment: Shouldn't the `grep` command print file names instead of lines with matches, like `$(grep --files-with-matches '/static' dir/*)`?

Comment: @Birei: Quite right (I copied the grep command from the question, should have checked more carefully). Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on using .$$. This works perfectly, and after further reading I understand it completely. Darn shame there is no work around where I can use the simple one liner.

Comment: @DaveCastillo: Well, you can write it on one (very long) line -- or you can put the commands in a shell script.

Comment: @KeithThompson I meant to say, it's a same I can't use the one liner that I described above(the one with the -i argument).

Comment: @DaveCastillo: Or you can install GNU sed.